# dataTable.AsEnumerable() in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net

In `Application_Start` I'm trying to filter datatable. In other code behind files I'm able to use `AsEnumerable()` of DataTable; but not in Global.asax. Any reason?

Comment: Well do you have `using System.Linq;` over there, Does it throw an error when you try `.AsEnumerable()` ?

Comment: It throws an error: Error 8 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and no extension method 'AsEnumerable' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Well `AsEnumerable()` takes no arguments, can you show your code ? (with the using statements ) ! !

Comment: var filtered = from entity in dt.AsEnumerable()
                           where entity.Field<int>("SerialNumber") == key
                           select entity;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made separate code behind file for `Global.asax`

Global.asax:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Language="C#" %>
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ....
        var filtered = from entity in dt.AsEnumerable()
                       .Where(entity => entity.Field<int>("SerialNumber") == key)
                       select entity;

        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: I think you want to show your code,then don't paste it answers area,you can edit your question...

Comment: This was actually the answer.

Comment: then you should have written that you have solved it yourself on top...:)